# Vanilla JavaScript: Filter nested array by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Consider the below array of posts:

```
posts_array =
[
 {
  id: 1,
  categories: [
   {
    category_id: 1,
    category_name: "one"
   },
   {
    category_id: 2,
    category_name: "two"
   },
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  categories: [
   {
    category_id: 1,
    category_name: "one"
   },
   {
    category_id: 3,
    category_name: "three"
   },
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  categories: [
   {
    category_id: 1,
    category_name: "one"
   },
   {
    category_id: 4,
    category_name: "four"
   },
   {
    category_id: 5,
    category_name: "five"
   },
 }    
]
```

I then have an array of category ids which I want to filter the above array with:

```
const category_id_array = [1, 4];
```

I would like to filter so that all conditions are met, i.e. return elements in posts_array that include **both** categories.category_id = 1 **and** categories.category_id = 4

I have tried with the below (with the .some function) but it returns elements where either condition is met, i.e. **either** categories.category_id = 1 **or** categories.category_id = 4

```
function filterPostsByCategoryIds(category_id_array){
    const filter_categories = category_id_array;
    const custom_filter = d => d.categories.some(c => filter_categories.includes(c.category_id));
    const filtered_posts_array = posts_array.filter(custom_filter);
    return filtered_posts_array;
}
```

Swapping .some with .every does not return any elements at all.

How can I filter posts_array by category_id_array, so that it returns the last element in the above example array, i.e. where categories include all category_id's from category_id_array?

Thanks and stay safe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.every()` on your `category_id_array` and return `true` when there is `.some()` object within the current `.categories` which has an `category_id` equal to that of the current id (`c`) from your `category_id_array`:

```js
const posts_array = [{ id: 1, categories: [{ category_id: 1, category_name: "one" }, { category_id: 2, category_name: "two" } ], }, { id: 2, categories: [{ category_id: 1, category_name: "one" }, { category_id: 3, category_name: "three" } ], }, { id: 3, categories: [{ category_id: 1, category_name: "one" }, { category_id: 4, category_name: "four" }, { category_id: 5, category_name: "five" } ], }];

function filterPostsByCategoryIds(category_id_array) {
  const custom_filter = d => category_id_array.every(c => d.categories.some(o => o.category_id === c));
  const filtered_posts_array = posts_array.filter(custom_filter);
  return filtered_posts_array;
}

const res = filterPostsByCategoryIds([1, 4]);
console.log(res);
```

You could also create a set of `category_id` for each object and then use `.every()` with `.has()` to check that the categories array has every id from the `category_id` like so:

```js
const posts_array = [{ id: 1, categories: [{ category_id: 1, category_name: "one" }, { category_id: 2, category_name: "two" } ], }, { id: 2, categories: [{ category_id: 1, category_name: "one" }, { category_id: 3, category_name: "three" } ], }, { id: 3, categories: [{ category_id: 1, category_name: "one" }, { category_id: 4, category_name: "four" }, { category_id: 5, category_name: "five" } ], }];

function filterPostsByCategoryIds(category_id_array) {
  return posts_array.filter(({categories}) => {
    const cat_ids = new Set(categories.map(({category_id}) => category_id));
    return category_id_array.every(id => cat_ids.has(id));
  });
}

const res = filterPostsByCategoryIds([1, 4]);
console.log(res);
```